# Keep getting random freezes after upgrading to 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.04

After upgrading to 19.04, I started getting random 10s freezes (only visual, could still hear audio). Happened more often if I was editing something in gimp.
However, after installing some updates yesterday I've started getting random permanent freezes. Everything freezes, audio glitches, and I have to perform a hard reset.

What do I do to debug this?

machine is Acer Aspire 3
nvidia drivers (ran ubuntu-drivers autoupdate and everything is up to date)